# avoid page refresh using jQuery ajax load() method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to avoid page refresh using ajax load. I am able to do it inside a div container by calling a controller method which returns view/partial view like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sublist").click(function () {
        $("#testing").load("/PartsCatalogue/" + this.id);
    });
});
```

Is it possible to load a completely new view ? instead of rendering a view/partial view inside a div container..

Please help.

Comment: unclear what do you mean by "completely new view". what do you want to happen **exactly**?

Comment: i am able to render a view/partial view inside a div container of a view. but i need to load a different view without page refresh using mvc.

Comment: You are again not so clear.. please state if you want SPA-behaviour or not